# How do gfortran -fcheck=bounds,pointer error reports come out

Tags: fortran, runtime-error, gfortran, sanitizer

I'm trying to use the `gfortran` option `-fcheck=bounds,pointer` to look for runtime errors in some code. What do the error reports look like, and where/when do they appear? Are they written to standard error, or output, or some file? Are they written and flushed at the point of occurrence, or at the end of execution? Does an error report terminate execution?

Answer (score 1):

In reverse order

- An error report does terminate execution
- This obviates whether they're buffered or flushed immediately
- They're written to standard error
- Passing an invalid pointer to a routine looks like this:

```
At line 556 of file ../../topslave.F
Fortran runtime error: Pointer actual argument 'buffer2' is not associated
```